# read last value from stack (java)

Tags: java, stack, netbeans-7

I created stack for store values as follows. I need to read last value from stack without using "**stack.pop**".

```
import java.util.Stack;

Stack stack = new Stack();
stack.push("Something");
stack.push("Something new");
```

Comment: `stack.peek()`?

Comment: Please provide more context. **Why** do you need to *read last value from stack without using "stack.pop"*'?

Comment: @Arkadiy I don't think explaining why is a necessity for asking a question that has a clear answer.

Comment: @G_H Well, I wasn't certain what OP was asking; which was why I made it a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class `Stack` extends class `Vector`, which has a `lastElement()` and `firstElement()` method that will return the last respectively first element in the collection.

After doing a test I can confirm that the top of the stack (the last element pushed in) is the last element, the bottom of the stack the first element. Also note that if such access is necessary, it might indicate you need a different data structure than a stack, but that depends on context. At any rate, Vector allows for random access.

If you just need the last element by this definition without popping it, using `peek()` as suggested by Elliott in his comment would be the appropriate method.

Comment: stack.peek() and stack.lastElement() both are correct.

Comment: Must remember that Stack doesnt allow random element access. So doing that through some APIs will be unethical. This is is the reason why we have such a  huge family of data structures.